# JavaImp plugin not able to parse Java files

Tags: java, vim, vim-plugin

I have been using the [JavaImp.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=325) script for auto importing Java statements in VIM
But trying out different directories in the JavaImpPaths, I am still unable to make JavaImp parse the Java files in the source to make auto imports possible

this is how my **.vimrc** looks like

```
let g:JavaImpPaths = "~/Documents/android-sdks/sources/android-21/android/content/" 
let g:JavaImpClassList = "~/.vim/JavaImp/JavaImp.txt" 
let g:JavaImpJarCache = "~/.vim/JavaImp/cache/"
```

This is what I get running JIG in new Vim window

```
:JIG  
 Do you want to create the directory ~/.vim/JavaImp/cache/?

Searching in path (package): ~/Documents/android-sdks/sources/android-21/android
/content/ ()  
Sorting the classes, this may take a while ...  
Assuring uniqueness...  
Error detected while processing function <SNR>10_JavaImpGenerate:  
line   75:
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
Done.  Found 1 classes (0 unique)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: How about contacting the plugin's author instead of asking random strangers for help?

Comment: Did that, still awaiting response. But I believe I may not be the first person using this plugin, and if its a common issue, some random stranger can surely help. Secondly, I think it might help someone in future.

Comment: 1. It looks like you are using the deprecated installation settings you want to use `g:JavaImpDataDir` instead of `g:JavaImpClassList` and `g:JavaImpJarCache`. 2. This plugin hasn't been updated since June 2004. This was before Java 5 came out. I wouldn't be surprised if it can't read modern java files as Java 5 introduced generics and a lot of other stuff. 3. Have you looked at [eclim](http://eclim.org)?

Comment: oh yes, but then  eclim comes with its own set of problems like, inability to make new projects in a super fast way or importing projects without opening the actual eclipse window.

Comment: You can do both of those from inside vim. I believe the commands are `:ProjectCreate` and `:ProjectImport`

Answer (score 0):

It might be late, but if anyone else comes along this might help them...

I got it working with the following changes to the script:

line 181 from

```
close
```

to

```
close!
```

And lines 207/208 from

```
let l:javaList = glob(a:cpath . "/**/*.java", 1, 1)
let l:clssList = glob(a:cpath . "/**/*.class", 1, 1)
```

to

```
let l:javaList = split(glob(a:cpath . "/**/*.java"), "\n")
let l:clssList = split(glob(a:cpath . "/**/*.class"), "\n")
```